# How to say "being under threat"

Tags: words, phrase-requests

How would you naturally say that something is "**under threat**"? For example:

> - The delivery is **under threat**
> - The contract is **under threat**
> - The agreed deadline is **under threat**

There are verbs like 脅かす｛おどかす｝and 脅迫｛きょうはく｝する, but I think they are used in cases of physical danger like natural disasters for example.

Answer (score 5):

How about 「[脅威]{きょうい}にさらされている」, 「[脅]{おびや}かされている」 or 「[危機]{きき}に[瀕]{ひん}している」?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use 「[危]{あや}ぶまれる」or「[危]{あや}ぶまれている」